# What does this mysql error means?

Tags: mysql

I get the following error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'AND `hackcount` >= 3' at line 1 SQL=SELECT COUNT(*) from 
`xxxxx_mi_iptable` WHERE ip = AND `hackcount` >= 3
```

What does this mean? What should I do to fix this?

Comment: please, put your code (the affected line at least)

Comment: `WHERE ip = AND` there is no test value for ip, check how you construct the string

Comment: That is the exact line I copied. I only changed the table prefix by 'xxxxx'. There was no IP mentioned. Probably I restored it in my PC, for which no IP was there, I don't know. :(

Answer (score 3):

There's an error in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ip = AND `hackcount` >= 3
```

Where `ip` equals *what*, exactly?  You forgot to put a value there.

Comment: That is the exact line I copied. I only changed the table prefix by 'xxxxx'. There was no IP mentioned. Probably I restored it in my PC, for which no IP was there, I don't know. :(

Comment: @DarKMaSk: None of that reply really made much sense to me.  But the problem with the code is clear, there's no value specified in the comparison which results in a syntax error.

Comment: Ok. Now if I have to specify a value, how I can do that/ Can you please guide me with exact steps?

Comment: @DarKMaSk: Well... Based on that question, it seems like the exact steps would include walking through some introductory tutorials on SQL.  The code you posted *already has* an example of including a value... The `3` at the end.  I mean, if you just *read the code aloud* you can see where the problem is just by finding where the words don't make sense.  I'm not really sure how else to explain it.  `ip = ` is an incomplete statement.  You need to complete the statement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Joomla plugin "Marco's SQL Injection" (http://www.mmleoni.net/sql-iniection-lfi-protection-plugin-for-joomla).

It has a line that tries to detect the IP of the current client

```
$remoteIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Because REMOTE_ADDR is not always present/reliable/sufficient the following SQL query

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from `#__mi_iptable` WHERE ip = '{$remoteIP}' AND `hackcount` >= {$this->p_ipBlockCount}" ;
```

fails.

the plugin should use something like this

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{
$remoteIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
$remoteIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
$remoteIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
```